# Dell Precision 7910 Ubuntu 14.04 freezes

Tags: 14.04, dell, freeze

I am currently running Ubuntu 14.04 LTS (fresh install) on a Dell Precision 7910.  When I attempt to do any heavy analysis (ie. processing 4-10 large files at one time), the machine completely freezes.  Neither the mouse nor keyboard respond, and I end up doing a hard reboot.  ALT + PrtScn + R E I S U B did not do anything.

I looked at the log files, but there is nothing there from the time of the freeze.

Although I am quickly able to reproduce this problem running a particular java program called GATK, I have also run into it while running C programs.  Sometimes it freezes right away, and other times it takes 20-30 minutes.

The Dell ePSA diagnostics test and memtest86+ test both passed.

Can anyone provide a step-by-step way to figure out what may be causing the system to freeze?

Thanks for your help!
RC

Comment: FYI, I also attempted to SSH into my machine to determine if this was a video problem, but was unable to.  I seems like an entire system freeze.

Comment: Which system log files were you checking, and do the programs that you are attempting to run, write their own logs?

Comment: I would first check video driver. Please add output of `lspci -k | grep -EA2 'VGA|3D` to your question.

Comment: @ Kevin:  The log files in   /var/log/  did not show anything.  And the program I am using does write a log file, but nothing was recorded there.  Everything was just ended abruptly.

Comment: @Pilot6:  Here is the output of video driver:  04:00.0 VGA compatible controller: NVIDIA Corporation GF119 [NVS 310] (rev a1)
 Subsystem: NVIDIA Corporation Device 094e
 Kernel driver in use: nouveau

Comment: Please [edit] your question and add full output of that command there. `lspci -k | grep -EA2 'VGA|3D'`. There was a typo in the previous one.

Answer (score 0):

I would start further investigating by monitoring system resources leading up to the freeze. Basic tools like `htop` or `top`, and `iotop` work well. Maybe RAM or swap is filling up, or disk I/O is being held by 1 process?

You can try setting the CPU affinity of your intensive process, or setting its niceness (I believe there is I/O niceness as well), to try to prevent resource starvation for kernel/system processes.

Answer (score 0):

After hours of googling, I read something similar where a complete system freeze was caused by some sort of error in the processor clock (?).  I went into the BIOS and disabled the "Intel Hyperthreading Technology", and this seems to have fixed it.  Although my machine now shows 8 cores, rather than 16 cores, it is no longer crashing.  I can live with this, however, if anyone has any ideas on how to enable the hyperthreading without major crashes, I would love to try it.

Thanks,
RC

Comment: Your problem is in a wrong video driver.

Comment: @Pilot6: I am unfamiliar with the details of video drivers.  Can you suggest a change I could make that would make the system more stable?  --Thanks, RC

Comment: That's what I am trying to do. Please read carefully my last comment to your question and do what I asked there. Then I will give you a solution.